# for loop problem, detect file with size and copy regardless of name

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

The situation:
I want to copy all odt files with size greater than 0 from one folder into another. Filenames will contain the following characters: + % & [ ( and spaces.

Here is my attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

mvfunc ()
{
        if [ -s "$1" ]; then
                cp -n "$1" /home/telas/zztmp/currentfiles/
                /usr/bin/truncate -s 0 "$1"
                return 0
        fi
}

fileslist=$(ls --quoting-style=shell-always /home/telas/zzz/workingfiles/*.odt)

for filename in "$fileslist" ; do
        mvfunc "$filename"
done
```

All help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: can you provide the sample file names ?

Comment: Use `for file in *.odt` directly instead of parsing `ls`.

Comment: You need an array list. Something like  `odtList=(*.odt);  for f in "${odtList[@]}"; do myfunc "$f"; done`  would be closer to your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather use pathname expansion ([globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)) in Bash than rely on external commands like `ls`.

If a `for` loop contains wildcards, then Bash uses globbing by default, so special characters won't mess like they would if interpreting the parameters given as a text string resulting from command substitution.

And the code will be cleaner and more portable, because `--quoting-style=` option is specific to GNU ls:

```
#!/bin/bash

mvfunc ()
{
        if [ -s "$1" ]; then
                cp -n "$1" currentfiles
                /usr/bin/truncate -s 0 "$1"
                return 0
        fi
}

for filename in /home/telas/zzz/workingfiles/*.odt; do
        mvfunc "$filename"
done
```

Comment: This won't work, because the file names might contain spaces.

Comment: @TBrandt And why exactly wouldn't it work? Did you test it? What was your result?

Comment: OK, my fault. When writing the glob directly after the "in" of the for loop, it seems to work (at least for bash and in cygwin). However, handling files and globs in Linux can be quite a problem, because filenames might contain wierd characters, such as space, tab, newline etc. Read http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html for an in-depth discussion about many of these problems.

Comment: @TBrandt If you're having problems with filenames containing special characters, it's because you're doing something that you shouldn't be doing, such as parsing the output of `ls` or using unquoted variable expansions. Read [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: I know all that but maybe I was a little too cautious.